# File dependend DAG execution

Tags: python, airflow

I build a DAG that begins with the download of a file over the SFTPOperator, I save it and proceed with accessing and processing it, with a PythonOperator.

I had no issues with this approach at all, till I started to scale up my celery-workers from 1 to 2.
Now I run in to the problem of a file that isn't available in both workers.

How do I solve it? Do I download the file over the SFTPHook and combine these Tasks?
Can I constrain the spread on to different workers?

kind regards,
CreedsCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a shared location between the workers. In case of multiple workers, you have no guarantee that two tasks will be run by the same worker.

An AWS EFS or something similar where you will download that file and later read, will be enough. I'm not good with infrastructure, so I can't help you with implementation details, but this is the solution I used for a similar problem.

Comment: Indeed! I also used azure blob storage for this in the past. The only other option is to combine the two operations into a single operator by using their hooks instead of operators.

Comment: Yea, I end up doing a similar way. I split the task into 2 DAGs. One that schedules; in my case the file downloads with the URL.  And the other one gets scheduled and just does his job.

Comment: @CreedsCode wouldn't it be easier for your case to use PythonOperator to do both the download and processing operations  as Jorrick Sleijster also said? In the same task that is. There are ways to download files through sftp using python directly. Also you can accept the answer if it answered your question